# Signin to Dropbox using access token

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I have used this code (from  Spring.NET Social Dropbox) to access Dropbox using a C# Winform application:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net-social-dropbox/blob/master/examples/Spring.ConsoleQuickStart/src/Spring.ConsoleQuickStart/Program.cs

```
DropboxServiceProvider dropboxServiceProvider = new DropboxServiceProvider(DropboxAppKey, DropboxAppSecret, AccessLevel.Full);
// Authorization without callback url
Console.Write("Getting request token...");
OAuthToken oauthToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.FetchRequestTokenAsync(null , null).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Done");
OAuth1Parameters parameters = new OAuth1Parameters();
string authenticateUrl = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.BuildAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken.Value, parameters);
Console.WriteLine("Redirect user for authorization");
Process.Start(authenticateUrl);
Console.Write("Press any key when authorization attempt has succeeded");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Getting access token...");
AuthorizedRequestToken requestToken = new AuthorizedRequestToken(oauthToken, null);
OAuthToken oauthAccessToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.ExchangeForAccessTokenAsync(requestToken, null).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Done");
IDropbox dropbox = dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi(oauthAccessToken.Value, oauthAccessToken.Secret);
DropboxProfile profile = dropbox.GetUserProfileAsync().Result;
```

But I see that one can get the access token directly as explained here:
https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/

So is it possible to use the access token manually obtained as in the second link to sign in to Dropbox?

I tried to pass the token directly to  `dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it possible to use the access token manually obtained as in the
>   second link to sign in to Dropbox?

If this is your question, the answer is NO. You cannot. Dropbox states that in the documentation.

> Note that the generated access token only works for your own Dropbox
>   account. **Once you deploy your app** to other users, you’ll need to **use
>   the standard OAuth authorization flow** to acquire tokens for each user.

Also, a bit on the library you are using. spring-net-social-dropbox was last updated at November 2012 while Dropbox API was OAuth 1.0. The OAuth2.0 version dropbox is now using was announced only at July 2013. This essentially means that *you are using an outdated library*.

The link for more current APIs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other

**Update**
Documentation for [DropNet](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet): http://dropnet.github.io/dropnet.html

Comment: -Would you please point me to where tokens are discussed in their documentation? I tried the other APIs but only this one worked for me.

Comment: @Jerry: do not use the *spring-net-social-dropbox* project. Its outdated and its using OAuth1.

Comment: Can you refer me to a working project for using any api.

Comment: I am sorry. SO is not really a give me the codez site. The documentation is complete. Did you read it?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The documentation isn't complete at all, like the rest of APIs that I checked. But I figured it out. I used `var _client = new DropNetClient(key, secret, token);`  and removed the rest of authentication code. Now no web authentication is required.

Comment: The first part of this answer is a weird mix of correct and incorrect. :-) Yes, you can of course use the access token you get from the app console to authenticate calls to the API—that's why it's there. And yes, that access token is for your account, so if you're building an app for other users, you'll need to use the OAuth flow to obtain access tokens for their accounts.

Comment: smarx, he is mentioning about this token which is given to developers for testing purposes. https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/. *To make this easier, we recently added the ability to generate an OAuth 2 access token for your account with the click of a button.*

Comment: @naveen Yes, I'm familiar. I'm the author of that blog post.

Comment: @naveen Then I'm not sure what (if anything?) we're disagreeing about. The access token you get from the app console is the same as you would get if you authorized your own account. If you're the only user of the app (as it seems in this case), that's the easiest way to authorize the app.

Answer (score 0):

The access token generated from the app console is an OAuth 2 access token, but the rest of your code appears to be using OAuth 1. If the library you're using supports OAuth 2, you should be able to use the generated access token. If it doesn't, then I'm afraid you'll have to obtain a token by going through the OAuth flow.

Comment: There is a namespace "using Spring.Social.OAuth2", but I couldn't find any documentation about it.